# GIT: Connect local sources (unknown state, no repo yet) with remote repository

Tags: git, repository

What's the workflow to connect local sources (not yet a repository, maybe behind, equal or ahead the remote repository) with a remote repository?

After that i want to see if the local sources are behind, equal or ahead the remote repository.

EDIT:
I don't want to backup local files first, then clone / pull from remote and overwrite with the backuped files after cloning / pulling.

Comment: Just pull the the repository and overwrite with your own files.

Comment: That's what i used to do. Isn't there a more elegant way without copying the files?

Comment: I don't know. I just saw the opportunity to help a git newbie like myself.

Comment: If you just downloaded the code instead of cloning, don't do that. Just clone the original repo. Fetch to see updates (e.g. you can see where origin/master is). Having a "detached" set of code does not integrate well if you want to then go back and use source control "sometimes".

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Use `git --git-dir=somesandbox/.git diff` to diff your local directory with a sandbox elsewhere on your file system.

**Details**

If you want to do the comparison from your local code to a fresh clone without turning your local code into a sandbox, you can use the `--git-dir` option to tell Git where you want it to compare from.

Assumptions:

- Let `local_src/` be where your source code is found, but not in a repo or sandbox.
- Let `BASE_URL/project.git` be your Git repo URL.

Steps:

- Clone the repo outside `local_src/`:

  `git clone BASE_URL/project.git`

  -> creates `project/`
- Do a git diff with respect to `project/.git`:

  `cd local_src/`

  `git --git-dir=../project/.git diff`

  compares the contents of `local_src/` with the commit checked out in `project/`.

  Add a branch name or other commit-ish to control what you're comparing with:

  `git --git-dir=../project/.git diff branch_or_tag_etc`

**Musings**

I agree with @crashmstr that this is not advisable as a normal workflow, but I use this approach when I have a copy of the code somewhere, distributed as a snapshot for example, and I want to analyse it without changing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track differences from an online git repository, the "elegant" solution is to just use git to clone the repo.

When you want to see what has changed in the online repo, `git fetch` (some GUI tools will do this for you automatically at intervals).

Fetch does not change any of *your* code or branches, it just updates the repo to have all of the changes that are online. You can then look at branches or changes to branches however you would normally look at changes. I use a GUI git client and can click to see what has changed.

Any other way of trying to avoid git and cloning the repo is going to add a number of additional steps. Also, if you ever want *updates* from the online repo, you have the tools to do so.

Comment: So a single 'git clone' will do for a one time check ?

Comment: You *start* with `git clone` always unless you never ever want to look at the online source again and only ever want that one version with no updates. Then sure, just download a zip of the source. Otherwise, use the source control system and clone the repo from the start. Then make whatever changes you want, fetch to see changes from the server, and let git do what git does: track changes.

Comment: This is not an answer for this question. Please see my edits. I know about clone / fetch / pull works. Thats not the question.

Comment: The question I see is "how do I track changes from a remote git repo". The answer to that is simply to clone the repo, do work and make changes as you want, and periodically fetch so you can compare with the current state of the remote. Any "workflow" outside of that is not using git as intended. If you want, you can redownload the code in a zip, extract, then use your favorite folder diff tool. But that is not using git.